# ldap nested group (attribute to look while parsing for group membership)

Tags: active-directory, nested

To retrieve groups belonging to all users I am using following filter:

```
(&(objectclass=*)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=sam,DC=aaaldap,DC=com))
```

And, i am able to retrieve multiple DN entries like:

```
1. GOT ENTRY: DN => CN=group1,CN=Users,DC=aaaldap,DC=com
 LDAP: Attribute                Length    Valueldap_get_dn
 1d21h: LDAP: cn                  6         group1

2. LDAP: GOT ENTRY: DN => CN=group2,CN=Users,DC=aaaldap,DC=com
 LDAP: Attribute                Length    Valueldap_get_dn
 1d21h: LDAP: cn                  6         group2
```

All i am interested is in group membership, so i want to parse the attribute CN received in the entry and would like to assume this as a group.

Can someone suggest if this will be a valid assumption of parsing CN attribute and mark its value as "group" membership to which it belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a real `objectClass` instead of just `*`, to limit the search to whatever object class you are using for groups. Then anything you get back must be a group. The search may also run faster.